# Is there any solution/alternate to cutting off issue while dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, dynamic, dynamic-sql

I am using a dynamic query for pivoting. My pivoted tables will have 250+ columns and with exceeding more than 8000 characters. Do we have any alternative for this? I am using SQL2008.

This is how I am making my SQL code. http://postimg.org/image/7iqux68d5/ (not the exact SQL but enough to show what I am trying to achieve.)

Thanks

Comment: The fact that you're attempting this is usually a symptom of a code smell.  If you post another question there may be a better solution - 250 columns is probably far too wide to be nicely read, and if this is common you may want to make it a view anyways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using print statement which can hold only max of 8000 that's why print is showing incomplete Query, so when you execute you will get the right answer after using NVARCHAR(MAX).

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the reply. I am getting the same error while executing it. I am using variable as:
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)
and executing it as 
EXEC (@SqL)

Comment: Not only @SQl query ,you also need to update the variable datatype to NVARCHAR(MAX) in which you are populating 250+ columns.

Comment: Tried this as well, but no luck. I wish I could show you the SQL statement.

Comment: I am trying to post the actual query here but "@" character for variable is not allowing me to post it.

Comment: Check the link to have an idea of how I am framing the query.
http://postimg.org/image/7iqux68d5/

Comment: can you provide your print query ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54427/discussion-between-raj-jayaswal-and-wumar).

Comment: from where you get @ColumntoSelect and what is the datatype. and one more thing once you define the variable nvarchar(MAX), you dont need to convert again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are worried about the string which you will store in a variable as it is exceeding the 8000 character lenght, right?

Then try this:

```
declare @string nvarchar(max);
```

See this worked at my end:

```
DECLARE @String nvarchar(max);
SELECT @String = REPLICATE(CAST('a' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)),100000);
SELECT LEN(@String)
```

Comment: Hi Nitin,
Yes, you got me right. I used NVARCHAR but the result is same. Even Print @SQL  is now showing the complete statement. It is cutting off.
Any suggestions further?

Comment: Did you tried Declaring it as NVARCHAR(MAX)? see my answer

Comment: Yes, tried it your way as well. It is giving me the same result.

Comment: Nithin, try to use a it within EXEC statement and try removing LEN function.